# Amazon Product Advertiising Api With Kindle Books (KDP)

Tags: amazon-product-api

I am using the Amazon Product Api to lookup ISBN's for books but when my program comes to an Kindle book the api can't find it. I am getting these ASIN's from KDP but I can't even find the book by searching amazon for the ASIN. What do I need to do with the KDP ASIN to make it work?

```
$this->conf = new GenericConfiguration();
$this->conf
            ->setCountry('com')
            ->setAccessKey('XXXXXXXXXXXXX')
            ->setSecretKey('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
            ->setAssociateTag('XXXXXXXXX-20')
            ->setRequest('\ApaiIO\Request\Soap\Request')
            ->setResponseTransformer('\ApaiIO\ResponseTransformer\ObjectToArray');

$this->apaiIo = new ApaiIO($this->conf);
$lookup = new Lookup();
$lookup->setItemId($ASIN);
$response = $this->apaiIo->runOperation($lookup);
```

The above code works for most books but not the KDP amazon books.

Comment: I have this question too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28915232/amazon-how-get-price-for-kindle-items have you found a solution?

Comment: I never did find a work around.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution per se, but you might want to use the Goodreads API (also owned by Amazon) to search for an ASIN. You will have to use the search by ISBN api call (it also works with asins). Note that not all asins on Amazon are on Goodreads, but all Goodreads asins are on Amazon.